# coldfusion ajax json data return data not in proper format

Tags: ajax, coldfusion

I am trying to return an array of struct through ajax to provide autocomplete feature.
I am trying to call **getEmployeeName** through ajax from the page where i want to populate the textbox.

The test.cfc is as follows:

```
<cfcomponent>
<cffunction name="getEmployeeName" access="remote" returnformat="JSON" >
    <cfargument name="term" type="string" required="yes">

    <cfset var returnArray=ArrayNew(1) />
    <cfset term=#Ucase(term)#>
    <cfquery name="getEmps" datasource="mines">
        ...
        <!--- my query ---!>
    </cfquery>

    <cfoutput>
    <cfloop query="getEmps">
        <cfset empStruct = StructNew() />
        <cfset empStruct["label"] = #emp_name# & " " &#desg_desc# & " " & #unit_name# />
        <cfset empStruct["value"] = #cpf_no#>

        <cfset ArrayAppend(returnArray,empStruct) />
    </cfloop>
    </cfoutput>
    <cfreturn #serializeJSON(returnArray)#>
</cffunction>
```

The ajax call is as follows:

```
$("#task_coordinator").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                     $.ajax({
                             url: "test.cfc?method=getEmployeeName",
                             type: "GET",
                             data: request,
                             success: function (data) {



                                    console.log(data);
                                    console.log(data.array([label]));

                             },
                             error: function(jqXHR, extStatus,errorThrown){
                                alert(errorThrown);
                             }
                     });
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {

            }
            ,minLength:5
    });
```

I have tried calling the method directly through the link to see whether it is working fine or not. At that it is returning only json data and not this extra information. My output has extra script before json data:

```
<script type="text/javascript">/* <![CDATA[ */_cf_loadingtexthtml="<img alt=' ' src='/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/resources/cf/images/loading.gif'/>";
_cf_contextpath="";
_cf_ajaxscriptsrc="/CFIDE/scripts/ajax";
_cf_jsonprefix='//';
_cf_websocket_port=8577;
_cf_flash_policy_port=1243;
/* ]]> */</script><script type="text/javascript" 
src="/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/messages/cfmessage.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/package/cfajax.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/CFIDE/scripts/cfform.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/CFIDE/scripts/masks.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/CFIDE/scripts/cfformhistory.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">/* <![CDATA[ */
    ColdFusion.Ajax.importTag('CFAJAXPROXY');
/* ]]> */</script>

<script type="text/javascript">/* <![CDATA[ */
    ColdFusion.Ajax.importTag('CFFORM');
/* ]]> */</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    _CF_checkCFForm_1 = function(_CF_this)
    {
        //reset on submit
        _CF_error_exists = false;
        _CF_error_messages = new Array();
        _CF_error_fields = new Object();
        _CF_FirstErrorField = null;


        //display error messages and return success
        if( _CF_error_exists )
        {
           if( _CF_error_messages.length > 0 )
           {
                // show alert() message
                _CF_onErrorAlert(_CF_error_messages);
                // set focus to first form error, if the field supports js focus().
                if( _CF_this[_CF_FirstErrorField].type == "text" )
                { _CF_this[_CF_FirstErrorField].focus(); }

            }
            return false;
        }else {
            return true;
        }
    }
//-->
</script>
[{"value":47455,"label":"BANTHIA ANUJA RAVINDRAKUMAR GRADUATE EXECUTIVE TRAINEE(E2) CENTRAL ESTABLISHMENT"}]
```

Can somebody tell me why this extra script is coming. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I didn't read all your code but I did read enough to see that you have a StructNew() function inside a loop.  That's a frequent cause of problems.

Comment: That extra code looks like there might be a `cfajaxproxy` tag in your CFM page. Also, your function should probably have a `returntype = "array"`. By using `returnformat="json"` you don't need the `SerializeJSON`. And you don't need the `<cfoutput>...</cfoutput>`.

Comment: @snackboy is correct. That additional script is added when you use `cfajaxproxy`.

Comment: I have not added cfajaxproxy tag in my code anywhere. Is it getting added implicitly or because of some settings?

Comment: Can you share your .cfm page assuming there is one. Also, try taking out the `<cfoutput></cfoutput>`.

Answer (score 0):

In your ColdFusion Administrator, select Debugging & Logging > Debugger Settings. You should find some settings in there to help debug AJAX requests. Try turning that off if it's checked.

[image]

Here's some info that might help.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec10e40-8000.html